# Pytorch Not Updating Variables in .step()

Tags: regression, linear-regression, pytorch, prediction

I'm attempting to convert old code to PyTorch code as an experiment. Ultimately, I will be doing regression on a 10,000+ x 100 Matrix, updating weights and whatnot appropriately.

Trying to learn, I'm slowly scaling up on toy examples. I'm hitting a wall with the following sample code.

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn 
import torch.nn.functional as funct  
from torch.autograd import Variable 



device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") 

x_data = Variable( torch.Tensor( [ [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0] ] ), 
requires_grad=True )
y_data = Variable( torch.Tensor( [ [2.0], [4.0], [6.0] ] ) ) 

w = Variable( torch.randn( 2, 1, requires_grad=True ) )

b = Variable( torch.randn( 1, 1, requires_grad=True ) )


class Model(torch.nn.Module) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super( Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(2,1) ## 2 features per entry. 1 output
    def forward(self, x2, w2, b2) :
        y_pred = x2 @ w2 + b2
        return y_pred


model = Model()

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss( size_average=False )
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD( model.parameters(), lr=0.01 )

for epoch in range(10) :
    y_pred = model( x_data,w,b ) # Get prediction
    loss = criterion( y_pred, y_data ) # Calc loss
    print( epoch, loss.data.item() ) # Print loss
    optimizer.zero_grad() # Zero gradient 
    loss.backward() # Calculate gradients
    optimizer.step() # Update w, b
```

However, doing so, my loss is always the same, and investigating shows my w and b never actually change.  I'm a bit lost at what's going on here.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to store the results of the "new" w and b to compare across iterations and datasets.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a case of cargo programming to me.

Notice that your `Model` class doesn't make use of `self` in `forward`, so it is effectively a "regular" (non-method) function, and `model` is entirely stateless. The simplest fix to your code is to make `optimizer` aware of `w` and `b`, by creating it as `optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([w, b], lr=0.01)`. I also rewrite `model` to be a function

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
# torch.autograd.Variable is roughly equivalent to requires_grad=True
# and is deprecated in PyTorch 1.0

# your code gives not reason to have `requires_grad=True` on `x_data`
x_data = torch.tensor( [ [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0] ])
y_data = torch.tensor( [ [2.0], [4.0], [6.0] ] )

w = torch.randn( 2, 1, requires_grad=True )
b = torch.randn( 1, 1, requires_grad=True )

def model(x2, w2, b2):
    return x2 @ w2 + b2

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss( size_average=False )
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([w, b], lr=0.01 )

for epoch in range(10) :
    y_pred = model( x_data,w,b )
    loss = criterion( y_pred, y_data )
    print( epoch, loss.data.item() )
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

That being said, `nn.Linear` is built to simplify this procedure. It automatically creates an equivalent of both `w` and `b`, called `self.weight` and `self.bias`, respectively. Also, `self.__call__(x)` is equivalent to the definition of forward of your `Model`, in that it returns `self.weight @ x + self.bias`. In other words, you can also use alternative code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x_data = torch.tensor( [ [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0] ] )
y_data = torch.tensor( [ [2.0], [4.0], [6.0] ] )

model = nn.Linear(2, 1)

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss( size_average=False )
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01 )

for epoch in range(10) :
    y_pred = model(x_data)
    loss = criterion( y_pred, y_data )
    print( epoch, loss.data.item() )
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

where `model.parameters()` can be used to enumerate model parameters (equivalent to the manually created list `[w, b]` above). To access your parameters (load, save, print, whatever) use `model.weight` and `model.bias`.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot.  PyTorch seems so useful and so powerful, but adapting is a bit tricky at the moment, so I appreciate this.  The reason I didn't just use nn.Linear is because, ultimately, my scaled up version will have more weights and factors and other things, so I'm trying to learn how to use it without some of the shortcuts.